# two dropdowns in one updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

there are two dropdowns in one updatepanel, both with autopostback=true
the only problem is that at first time that dropdown value change, both events (ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged AND ddlPackage_SelectedIndexChanged) were called.
after first time, every thing will be OK, and each event is called just on change of related dropdown index.

here is my code :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPackage" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlCountry" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlPackage" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="divManagerBoxSection">
            <asp:Label CssClass="lblManagerBox" ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="کشور"></asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="ddlManagerBox ddlCountry" ID="ddlCountry"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="0" Enabled="false">انتخاب کنید</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">ایران</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2">تایلند</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3">ترکیه</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="4">روسیه</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        <div class="divManagerBoxSection">
            <asp:Label CssClass="lblManagerBox" ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="پکیج"></asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList CssClass="ddlManagerBox ddlPackage" ID="ddlPackage" runat="server"
                AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPackage_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Value="0" Enabled="false">انتخاب کنید</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">4 شب پاتایا 3 شب بانکوک</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2">3 شب پوکت 3 شب سامویی</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3">پکیج جدید ...</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and C# :

```
        protected void ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListItem lst = new ListItem("A", "0");
        ddlCity1.Items.Insert(ddlCity1.Items.Count, lst);
    }

    protected void ddlPackage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListItem lst = new ListItem("B", "0");
        ddlCity1.Items.Insert(ddlCity1.Items.Count, lst);
    }
```

changing value of ddlCountry results on ddlCity:

A
B
A
A
A

and changing value of ddlPackage results on ddlCity:

A
B
B
B
B

no different which dropdown value is changing for first time, both events run.
any help would be graciously appreciated.

Comment: I mean dropdown value changing

Comment: Is your update panel inside another update panel? If not, you don't need UpdateMode="Conditional". I would take that out, set ChildrenAsTriggers to true, remove the triggers and try it.

Comment: thank you, I removed Conditional mode, and I set ChildrenAsTriggers to True, nothing changed, I'll improve my question with some codes and you can test it yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you don't have a default value on DropDownLists, so in the first calling the Codebehind thinks that "Null" is changed to "A Value" (for instance: 4 شب پاتایا 3 شب بانکوک).
The value (4 شب پاتایا 3 شب بانکوک) is shown as default selected value in output, but is not considered as selected value in codebehind and is flagged as a change in first call.
In both DropDownLists select an item as a default value and the problem has been solved.
Like this:

```
<div class="divManagerBoxSection">
    <asp:Label CssClass="lblManagerBox" ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="کشور"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="ddlManagerBox ddlCountry" ID="ddlCountry"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="0" Enabled="false">انتخاب کنید</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1" Selected="True">ایران</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">تایلند</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">ترکیه</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="4">روسیه</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
<div class="divManagerBoxSection">
    <asp:Label CssClass="lblManagerBox" ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="پکیج"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList CssClass="ddlManagerBox ddlPackage" ID="ddlPackage" runat="server"
        AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPackage_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Value="0" Enabled="false">انتخاب کنید</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1" Selected="True">4 شب پاتایا 3 شب بانکوک</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">3 شب پوکت 3 شب سامویی</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">پکیج جدید ...</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

Look at the `Selected="True"` for first enabled items in both DDLs.